# Blazor HttpRequestException:TypeError:Failed to fetch

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-core, blazor

I have a blazor application and trying to post a record via .net core api.
When I make a post request blazor throws an error:
*HttpRequestException: TypeError:Failed to fetch
at system.Net.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpsRequestMessagé request,HttpCompletionOption completionOption,boolean async,Boolean async,Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, Cancellation Token cancellationToken)*

since I'm pretty new to blazor and api, can't figure out where the problem is.

.net core Web api controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[HttpPost]
Public async Task <IactionResult> AddColumn ([FromQuery]Column column)
{
 var response=await _repository.Insert (column)
return Ok (response)
}
```

Blazor application;

```
private async void AddNewColumn ()
{
Column column=new Column {Name="eric",Isvisible=true,Order=10};
var response=await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<Column>("/api/Column/AddColumn",column);
}
```

I tested AddColumn method on swagger and it works perfectly fine.
Also I don't get any errors while trying to get records via api which makes me ensure that the issue is not related with base adress.
I'm waiting for your helps.

Comment: I think you need to change [FromQuery] to [FromBody] since you are sending data in body of the request..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' error when trying to call AspNetCore Restful API from Blazor Wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311181/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-error-when-trying-to-call-aspnetcore-restfu)

Answer (score 5):

In the web api project, do the following.

If you have Startup.cs file, then find the configure method and add the following in the very beginning of the method(not in the end, it wont work).

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  // Add the following right in the beginning.
  app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin  
    .AllowCredentials());               // allow credentials 

  // Other config will come after this.
}
```

If you are in the latest .net 6 and above project types, then open the program.cs.

In there you add the same code as above. It should look as follows.

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin  
    .AllowCredentials());               // allow credentials
```

Comment: Thanks. do you have any idea what should to do if it doesn't work even with this CORS configuration?!

Comment: No, not sure... For my case, I got it to work that way.

Comment: Thanks @VivekDev the last sample of code for .Net 6 and above unlocked the situation for me.

Comment: If you are .net 6+, also remember to add `builder.Services.AddCors();`