# Can't connect to external ip address via HTTPClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, opensilver

When i try to execute this
MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace OpenSilverApplication3
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            TestTod();
        }
        private async void TestTod()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Testing.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    Testing.Text = $"Server error {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml code:

```
<sdk:Page
    x:Class="OpenSilverApplication3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OpenSilverApplication3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d" 
      
    Title="Page1" Background="White" >
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Testing" Width="450" Height="250" Text="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FFD9D9D9" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
</sdk:Page>
```

nothing happens.

If i enter this link("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO") in browser, then page opens with data in JSON format. The database I'm connecting to is on a private server, so it doesn't have a domain name. This server use Apache 2.4.

I replace link("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO") on this link("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") and then code execute correctly.

I use VS 2022. Using OpenSilver(https://opensilver.net/)
Maybe I need give permissions to the application for connect to external ip-addresses?

I test this link("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO") in fiddler. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMp6t.png)

Test with this link("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO")
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ3JO.png)

Test with this link("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlY53.png)

I changed code to catch error.

```
namespace OpenSilverApplication3
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            TestTod();
        }
        private async void TestTod()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://89.208.81.184:1337/DnD1C/hs/DNDAPI/V1/GETINFO");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Testing.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Testing.Text = $"Server error {response.StatusCode}";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Testing.Text = ex.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I got:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at OpenSilverApplication3.MainPage.TestTod() in C:\Users\NyComp\source\repos\OpenSilverApplication3\OpenSilverApplication3\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 30
```

Comment: "nothing happens" - HttpClient does not have such behavior. It either returns some data or fails in some way... Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and make sure to specify exactly what happens. You may want to additionally capture outgoing requests with Fiddler (or other HTTP debugger of your choice) and add that info to the question.

Comment: How did you try to execute the code?

Comment: What does Testing.Text mean? Maybe try to dump the response to the console instead. You should see at least some kind of error

Comment: [Execute](https://postimg.cc/943SrdLM).

Comment: My guess: You are not allowed to use unsecure http connections but https only. Put your code in appropriate try catch and see if there's an error.

Comment: `TestTod();` This is the reason why nothing happens, if it is executed in this way, the task won't throw any exception. Use `Task.Exception` property to find out the problem.

Comment: If I run your code it runs perfectly fine without any issues

Comment: Maybe you have permission to connect via an insecure connection in visual studio? If so, how to do it?

Comment: if it's the insecure http what causes the problem maybe it helps to call the site with your silver app also without https. Sometimes insecure sites are allowed to make insecure requests.

Comment: Klamsi, can you please specify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This error message probably has to do with CORS. I know, the error message does not help... you can see more details here: [Getting 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' error when trying to call AspNetCore Restful API from Blazor Wasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311181/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-error-when-trying-to-call-aspnetcore-restfu)